# ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from partially initialized module 'dash' - python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, importerror, dashboard, plotly-python

I'm very new to python/dash/plotly and I keep getting the same error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from partially initialized module 'dash' (most likely due to a circular import)

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've imported the following:

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.io as pio
```

Comment: is the name of your file dash.py? don't name any of your files after the same names as modules, it can confuse the module importer; that may be one culprit

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"most likely due to a circular import": this is probably due to your file being named as a dash or as a module name.

But I got the error message

ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash'

For me reinstalling dash fixed the issue.

1. pip3 uninstall dash
2. pip3 install dash

Comment: for me this was due to naming the file dash.py which conflicted with dash (the package)